# Logic behind placing monorail motor on front wheel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am currently working on this exercise and cannot find the logic. This is the exercise:
[image]

(Note, this does not violate the rule about homework posting since I do not want help with solving this exercise.)

The solution manual says B is best since there will be a CCW torque around some point above G. This does not make sense. If the torque is CCW then there should be a greater downward force on A than on B. I can only think about cars where you want rear-wheel drive when doing drag racing since a car with 50/50 weight distribution will have more grip on the rear when accelerating hard enough. Why does this become different? I am really confused about all of this now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious difference between this overhead monorail and the drag racer is that here the Centre of Mass G is **below** the points at which the friction forces act, whereas for the drag racer the Centre of Mass G is **above** the points at which friction acts.

Friction from the overhead rails creates a CW torque about G, which tends to lift A off the rail and press B into it, enabling greater traction at B. Whereas for the racer the torque about G is CCW which tends to press the rear wheel into the ground and increase traction there.

Instead of using the ground frame of reference and analysing this as a **dynamics** problem, it is often more convenient - and possibly less confusing - to use the accelerating frame of reference (in which the car is at rest) and analyse this as a **statics** problem. To use such non-inertial frames of reference you need to include **inertial forces** where appropriate, such as centrifugal and Coriolis forces in a rotating frame of reference. Here if the monorail car accelerates at $a$ to the **right** in the ground frame there is an inertial force $ma$ acting on the CM of the car to the **left** in the accelerating frame, where $m$ is the mass of the car. You can then balance all forces and torques as for a normal statics problem.